# Pumpkin seedlings dying off?

Tags: pumpkins

I planted a few pumpkin seeds in pots 2 to a pot and left in my greenhouse, after about 4 weeks I had 2 lovely looking plants in one pot each with 3 leaves, at this point I transplanted them each into there own bigger pot. Within about a week one and then the other went really limp, turned light green almost yellow and then died off.

I have been watering and each has been sat in a tray to ensure I don’t over water, any suggestions what I can do differently next time?

I am in the UK and April this year has been unseasonally hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squash family does not like to have their roots disturbed. Turning a plant out of its pot for planting outside is not a problem provided the pot is fairly full of roots, but separating seedlings like that is asking for trouble.

An alternate process is to still put 2 seeds to a pot (germination will be often 2, sometimes 0 but nearly always at least 1), but leave them grow to fill the pot. Then you can either plant the pair as is outside with confidence since the pot will be full and leave both to grow or snip one off at soil level to allow the other to grow to maturity by itself.

The heat will not have been a problem, squash likes heat provided there is adequate water.